# Columns not lining up when using radio buttons in bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Having an issue with the bootstrap grid columns not lining up when using radio buttons in the grid. essentially all the columns should line up exactly but they are not. The example has virtually no styling but as you can see the columns are not lining up as you would expect. Goal is to make the column and rows dynamic so user can add and edit new column and rows.

You need to expand the snippet to see the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio Bootstrap Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .row {
        outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }

      [class*="col-md"] {
        outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      .textAlignCenter {
        text-align: center;
      }

      label {
        padding: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Same/Different Example</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Very <br>Disinterested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Somewhat <br>Disinterested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Somewhat <br>Interested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Very <br>Interested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="col-md-4">Travel</label>
            <div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class=" col-md-4">Fashion</label>
            <div class="cbl -radio">
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class=" col-md-4">Health &amp; Fitness</label>
            <div class="cbl -radio">
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap table to fix align.
Or replace the code using this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Radio Boostrap Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    table,th,tr,td,thead,tbody {
        border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="container py-5">

        <form novalidate="novalidate">
            <h4 class="">Same/Different Example</h4>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Very <br>Disinterested</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Somewhat <br>Disinterested</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Somewhat <br>Interested</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Very <br>Interested</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Travel</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="travel" value="Very Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="travel" value="Somewhat Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="travel" value="Somewhat Interested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="travel" value="Very Interested"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="fashion" value="Very Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="fashion" value="Somewhat Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="fashion" value="Somewhat Interested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="fashion" value="Very Interested"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Health &amp; Fitness</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="health" value="Very Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="health" value="Somewhat Disinterested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="health" value="Somewhat Interested"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="health" value="Very Interested"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ah yeah so table is what I originally had and I wanted to use but design requirements are limiting me to the bootstrap grid, I have a other CSS that becomes misaligned because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a suitable solution for radio and check input specific row/columns. For those specific rows I eliminated the gutters on the cols using the following CSS:

```
.no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Radio Boostrap Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .row {
        outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      }

      [class*="col-md"] {
        outline: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      .textAlignCenter {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
    .no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
          padding-right: 0;
          padding-left: 0;
        }
      
      label {
        padding: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="container-fluid" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Same/Different Example</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class=""></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Very <br>Disinterested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Somewhat <br>Disinterested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Somewhat <br>Interested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Very <br>Interested </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="col-md-4">Travel</label>
            <div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested" onclick="socratesProcess.ToggleRadioSelection(event,'Dataset.Scratch.Text6')">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested" onclick="socratesProcess.ToggleRadioSelection(event,'Dataset.Scratch.Text6')">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested" onclick="socratesProcess.ToggleRadioSelection(event,'Dataset.Scratch.Text6')">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-md-2 textAlignCenter">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested" onclick="socratesProcess.ToggleRadioSelection(event,'Dataset.Scratch.Text6')">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class=" col-md-4">Fashion</label>
            <div class="cbl -radio">
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label class=" col-md-4">Health &amp; Fitness</label>
            <div class="cbl -radio">
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Disinterested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Somewhat Interested">
              </div>
              <div class=" form-check textAlignCenter col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" value="Very Interested">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```